# How to detect if perfectly divisible?

Tags: pine-script, trading, tradingview-api

What code to use to know if the number is perfectly divisible, meaning it has no reminder.

4/2 = 0 perfectly divisible

5/2 = 2.5 not divisible.

What code can i use to detect this in pine script?

Comment: Modulus, gives you the remainder if there is one, 0 if perfect.  https://kodify.net/tradingview/operators/modulus-operator/

Answer (score 0):

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_{percent}](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#op_%7Bpercent%7D)

```
modulo == 0?
```

"We will use the modulo operator, % , to check if one number is evenly divisible by another number. The modulo operator gives the remainder obtained by dividing two numbers. If a number is evenly divisible, the operation will return 0."

I'd imagine:

```
a % b == 0?
```